# Best way to calculate sum depending on dates with SQL

Tags: sql, date, sum

I don't know a good way to maintain sums depending on dates in a SQL database.

Take a database with two tables:

**Client**

- clientID
- name
- overdueAmount

**Invoice**

- clientID
- invoiceID
- amount
- dueDate
- paymentDate

I need to propose a list of the clients and order it by overdue amount (sum of not paid past invoices of the client). On big database it isn't possible to calculate it in real time.

The problem is the maintenance of an overdue amount field on the client. The amount of this field can change at midnight from one day to the other even if nothing changed on the invoices of the client.

This sum changes if the invoice is paid, a new invoice is created and due date is past, a due date is now past and wasn't yesterday...

The only solution I found is to recalculate every night this field on every client by summing the invoices respecting the conditions. But it's not efficient on very big databases.

I think it's a common problem and I would like to know if a best practice exists?

Comment: Just a thought: Can't you Calculate OverdueAmount only for the  clients whose having invoices which InvoiceDate, 
DueDate and PaymentDate is within the lastdate,  and run the process at sheduled time each day
(there should be a method to ensure that the previous day process is OK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about data warehousing. It will help you to solve this problem. It looks similar as what you just said

> "The only solution I found is to recalculate every night this field
>   on every client by summing the invoices respecting the conditions. But
>   it's not efficient on very big databases."

But it has something more than that. When you read it, try to forget about normalization. Its main intention is for 'show' data, not 'manage' data. So, you would feel weird at beginning but if you understand 'why we need data warehousing', it will be very very interesting.

This is a book that can be a good start [http://www.amazon.com/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Complete-Dimensional/dp/0471200247](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471200247) , classic one.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd like to understand what you mean by "very big databases" - most RDBMS systems running on decent hardware should be able to calculate this in real time for anything less than hundreds of millions of invoices. I speak from experience here.

Secondly, "best practice" is one of those expressions that mean very little - it's often used to present someone's opinion as being more meaningful than simply an opinion.

In *my* opinion, by far the best option is to calculate it on the fly.

If your database is so big that you really can't do this, I'd consider a nightly batch (as you describe). Nightly batch runs are a pain - especially for systems that need to be available 24/7, but they have the benefit of keeping all the logic in a single place.

If you want to avoid nightly batches, you can use triggers to populate an "unpaid_invoices" table. When you create a new invoice record, a trigger copies that invoice to the "unpaid_invoices" table; when you update the invoice with a payment, and the payment amount equals the outstanding amount, you delete from the unpaid_invoices table. By definition, the unpaid_invoices table should be far smaller than the total number of invoices; calculating the outstanding amount for a given customer on the fly should be okay.

However, triggers are nasty, evil things, with exotic failure modes that can stump the unsuspecting developer, so only consider this if you have a ninja SQL developer on hand. Absolutely make sure you have a SQL query which checks the validity of your unpaid_invoices table, and ideally schedule it as a regular task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe "pattern" would be a better term than "best practice". My database is not so big, 4 million clients and arround 30 million invoices. The problem is that to sort by overdue amount it is necessary to calculate on every client the amount. And this kind of list is used by the users all day.